# How to pass dynamic params to jenkins resource method in python?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to extend Jenkins shared library with some python functions which I have in my resources directory. I can call the function in my jenkins pipeline but I am struggling to pass params.

In my jenkinsfile I tried the following

```
script{
     getLabelsPerPullRequest.runMyPython(git_url="${env.GIT_URL}", github_token="${env.GITHUB_CREDENTIALS_ID}", prNbr_name="${BRANCH_NAME}") 
}
```

where `getLabelsPerPullRequest.runMyPython` in vars folder looks like this:

```
def runMyPython(String git_url, String github_token, String prNbr_name) {
  final pythonContent = libraryResource('com/sophia/sharedlib/getLabelsPerPullRequest.py')
  sh('echo ${git_url} ${github_token} ${prNbr_name}')
  writeFile(file: 'getLabelsPerPullRequest.py', text: pythonContent)
  sh('chmod +x getLabelsPerPullRequest.py && ./getLabelsPerPullRequest.py -u ${git_url} -t ${github_token} -p ${prNbr_name}')
}
```

`echo` not returning anything. How can I pass the params from pipeline to the function?

The goal is to be able to use the passed params to substitute the flags in the last `sh` command. I can run a python script with no params using the same method, but these can only do so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shared library function `runMyPython` is fine, just use double quotes `""` instead of single quotes `''` to enable the string interpolation and the substitution of variables:

```
("echo ${git_url} ${github_token} ${prNbr_name}")
```

Another thing is that as far is i know groovy does not support named arguments like you used it, it supports [named arguments as map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.0-beta-1/html/documentation/#_named_arguments), so you will need to update you call to the shared library method to:

```
getLabelsPerPullRequest.runMyPython(env.GIT_URL, env.GITHUB_CREDENTIALS_ID, BRANCH_NAME)
```

or alternatively change your `runMyPython` function to receive a map, and then use the `param:value` notation to call it.